# Apple MapKit JS (web) - Max Camera Zoom

Tags: javascript, mapkit, mapkit-js

Apple's [MapKit JS](https://developer.apple.com/maps/web/) (for the web) is in beta.

I am trying to zoom out the camera so that the entire world is visible without needing to scroll or zoom, but there seems to a cap on the maximum zoom level.

I have tried setting the `cameraZoomRange` and `cameraDistance` properties on the map but have had no luck. These values are in meters (according to the documentation), but there is no reference to the maximum value supported. Does anyone know if there is a solution to this?

```
map.cameraZoomRange = new mapkit.CameraZoomRange(1000000000000, 1000000000000)
// or
map.cameraDistance = 1000000000000
```

[image: Example implementation showing max zoom level.]

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things going on here:  the size of the tiles served from MapKit + the size of your Map, and the *unpublished* maximum camera distance (as you noted).  I recommend adding extra logging to find what the computed Camera Distance for your map is (as it is related to where you center coordinate is).

1. MapKit JS serves up tiles that are 512x512 (for Retina/hDPI devices), so the number of tiles served for a particular zoom depends on the pixel dimensions of your map `<div>` and the capabilities of your device.  Through testing, MapKit JS does not appear to serve tiles below Zoom Level 1.  You can find this by inspecting the images served via *Inspect Element* > *Network* > *Images*.
2. You can use the MapKit JS docs on [Handling Map Events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs/mapkit/map/handling_map_events) to print out empirical Camera Distance values to the Javascript console.

```js
map.addEventListener("region-change-end", function(event)    {
  console.log("cameraDistance = " +
    mapkit.maps[0].cameraDistance.toFixed(3)
  );
});
```

---

Example data for a 600x600 px `#map`, centered at Sydney, NSW.  Through empirical tests, I have estimated the relation between camera distance and a zoom level you would find in Mapbox or Leaflet SDK for JavaScript.

*estimated* Zoom Level = 25 - Floor(log<sub>2</sub>(`cameraDistance`))

| `cameraDistance` in meters Centered around Australia | Estimated Zoom 25 - Floor(log<sub>2</sub>(`cameraDistance`)) |
| --- | --- |
| 18,817,301.985 | 1 |
| 1,176,081.374 | 5 |
| 36,752.543 | 10 |
| 1,148.517 | 15 |
| 35.891 | 20 |
| 4.486 | 23 |

[image: Zoom = 1]